# Execute Membership.createuser(user,password,email) using only t-sql syntax

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, password-encryption

I modified a mvc3 application of my company to implement a Role Provider with a role 'admin' which can give permissions to/delete other users.

This has been pretty straight-forward, the problem i'm facing is to add the first 'admin' user by sql syntax, because the Membership Provider uses a hash+salt combination to store user password so inserting a clear password and empty salt won't work.

Is there a way to achieve this by sql, or executing .net code in sql server without loading a CLR assembly?

Thanks!

Comment: Replication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124768/sql-to-create-net-membership-provider-users ?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like i didn't search enough :) anyway i already solved it by asigning roles with sql to an already existing user known to me, is a much simpler solution.